# Editable DataTables

Tags: php, jquery, datatable

I'm using Datatables and all works well with being able to edit simple data ie Names etc, what I'm trying to understand how I get it to have a DateTime Picker and SELECT OPTION with in it.

I have 2 columns that I want edit, as I say one being a DateTime and the other I want to add a SELECT Option.

This is my code so far, when reading about them through [datatables-editable](http://jquery-datatables-editable.googlecode.com/) it isn't quite clear how I can achieve this especially when my Editable.js doesnt look anything like theirs.

Can you give me advice on how I can get them both to be added in, so it is easier for my end users to update the info.

```
var oTable = $('#tobebookedtable').dataTable();
oTable.$('td').editable( '../../../includes/planning/plg_tobebooked_edit.php', {
tooltip: 'Click to edit...',
"callback": function(sValue, y) {
    var aPos = oTable.fnGetPosition(this);
    oTable.fnUpdate(sValue, aPos[0], aPos[1]);
},
"submitdata": function (value, settings) {
    return {
        "row_id": this.getAttribute('id'),
        "column": oTable.fnGetPosition(this)[2]
    };
},
"height": "26px",
"width": "100%"        
});
```

I tried with a test SELECT putting it after `"width": "100%"` but this just appeared in every column when you click to edit

```
type : 'select',
style   : 'display: inline',
data : "{'A':'Test A','B':'Test B','C':'Test C'}"
```

My table

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered" id="tobebookedtable">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Address</th>
        <th>Postcode</th>
        <th>Planned</th>
        <th>TimeSlot</th>
        <th>ByWho</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <?php
        $plg = db::getInstance()->query('CALL sp_tobebooked()');
        foreach ($plg->results() as $plg) {
    ?>
    <tr id="<?php echo $plg->ID; ?>">
        <td><?php echo $plg->Address; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $plg->Postcode; ?></td>
        <td id="<?php echo $plg->ID; ?>"><?php echo $plg->Planned; ?></td>
        <td id="<?php echo $plg->ID; ?>"><?php echo $plg->TimeSlot; ?></td>
        <td id="<?php echo $plg->ID; ?>"><?php echo $plg->ByWho; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php }; ?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

test example from TCHdvlp's advice

```
$('#tobebookedtable').dataTable( {
//for each generated row
"createdRow": function( row, data, dataIndex ) {
    //create the dropdown
    var myDropDown = $('<select><option value=""></option><option value="Yes">Yes</option><option value="No">No</option></select>');
    //bind this dropdown with the JS object used by dataTable
    myDropDown.on("change",function(){
        data.ByWho = $(this).val();
    });
    //inject this dropdown in the desired column
    $(row).find("td:eq("+data.ByWho+")").html(myDropDown);
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to achieve this. You don't need "editable.js". All is done with this option [createdRow( row, data, dataIndex )](https://datatables.net/reference/option/createdRow) from dataTable plugin.

Here is to use it :

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
    //for each generated row
    "createdRow": function( row, data, dataIndex ) {
        //create the dropdown
        var myDropDown = $("<select>").....
        //bind this dropdown with the JS object used by dataTable
        myDropDown.on("change",function(){
            data.nameOfTheOptionAttribute = $(this).val();
        });
        //inject this dropdown in the desired column
        $(row).find("td:eq("+indexOfColumnDropdown=")").html(myDropDown);
    }
});
```

And your done !

If you want to initialise your dropdown/input/datepicker/whatever, you can do it in this same function. So you don't "erase" the data with `.html()`

```
...
var myDropDown = $("<select>").....
initMyDropdown(data.nameOfTheOptionAttribute)
...
```

Other example : transform simple data into editable field

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
    //for each generated row
    "createdRow": function( row, data, dataIndex ) {
        var price = data.price !=null ? data.price : 0;
        var inputPrice = $("<input type='text' class='editprice' value='" + price + "' />");
        inputPrice.on("blur",function(){
            data.price = $(this).val();
        });
        $(row).find("td:eq(" + indexOfColPrice + ")").html(inputPrice);
    }
});
```

Here there is the working example :
http://jsfiddle.net/TCHdevlp/fq9e1z89/

Comment: Thanks, for the post, so will this enable me to edit the data within the fields, so that I can post it back to the database?

Comment: Sure ! There will be a dropdown in this cell, or a datepicker or whatever. For instance, I transform simple money values into inputs. Let me show you, (I'll edit my answer)

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying to understand what it does... The indexOfColPrice in your example where does that come from?

Comment: In your example you have `<input type='text' class='editprice' value='" + price + "' />` would you build this is you would if you were just creating a standard pager form?

Comment: it has been declared before in my file, with others variables... So that, if you need to add a column, one day, you just have to change the variable value once, for all the file...

Comment: Basically, yes ! But in my project, I'm submitting my forms with ajax, that's an other concern.

Comment: Ok but does it represent what is the actual field? In my example table above, its the ByWho field from my database which I want to use a SELECT OPTION with and Planned to use the DATETIME

Comment: My update is through the PHP page I use within the URL option, this then gets the row id, value & column to then use and UPDATE SQL to update the DB

Comment: Unfortunatly, you must create your dropdown from scratch. It's up to you to add options in the select. That is what my `....` mean.

Comment: Ok I understand that about dropdowns, but I dont understand how the variable indexOfColPrice comes in, in this case what do you think I declare?

Comment: Using your example I edited my original post to show my version of your example. I get this error within Console log `Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment ` what does this mean?

Comment: there is a mistake here `$(row).find("td:eq("+EPCByWho=")").html(myDropDown);` The `=` sign has nothing to do here

Comment: Ah ok thanks, how can I define the column to fit into the variable for this line?

Comment: according to the doc : http://www.datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/object_dom_read.html If think `data.nameOfTheOptionAttribute` will be `ByWho` or `data.ByWho`

Comment: Thanks I've altered that point and used data.ByWho is in the example on my first post. When I run the table now it runs without error which is great. My only issue is that the table is no longer editable, I cant click on to the particular row field and see the drop down. It's like a static table. How/Why would this be?

Comment: `$(row).find("td:eq("+data.ByWho+")").html(myDropDown);` It can't find the cell at index `data.ByWho`. It must be a integer. replace simply for testing by `$(row).find("td:eq(4)").html(myDropDown);`

Comment: Ah brilliant thanks :-) yes, that shows a drop down option, one problem I have though when I changed the drop down to suit the list I need to show, it will get rid of any data that was in the column when pulled in from the database.

Comment: you mean `$plg->ByWho` must be one of the options ? In this case, reffers to my sample with `price`

Comment: Ah makes more sense to me that bit now  will give it a go. Thanks